# Why is indentation important when analysing code?

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors, transpiler

I am getting an error while transpiling sass to css, "Line X: Inconsistent indentation: Y spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented !Y spaces"

Here is the error state of my sass code:

```
header 
{
     margin: 50px;
     background-color: #2aa4df;

     div 
     {

     } 
       p 
       { 
           margin-top: 0;
       }
}
```

As you can see, near the p style rule I have used a different indentation which produces the error. What I'm wanting to know is why indention is important from a compiler perspective

Comment: how you are compiling the sass file?

Answer (score 4):

Indentations errors are not related to `sass` transpiler, the sass transpiler never mind converting unindented source code. You can try this - https://www.sassmeister.com/ and paste your above code. It works perfectly without any error.

I think there is some css `lint` setting which is not allowing that indentation and due to that, you are getting those error. Please look for `lint` settings in your project.

Comment: My settings.json file does not contain any settings for css files ' "[css]": {}'

Comment: can you please remove your "@Bobstar89 done" comment? I've rephrased my question to make it more useful